# Adding Dynamic functionality to a Graph

Tags: dynamic, graphs-and-networks

I would like to make the edges and vertices of a `Graph` interactive, a simple demonstration is to change their colors:

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green},
 Dynamic@Graph[{
    EventHandler[
     Style[1, col], 
       {"MouseClicked" :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}],
    2, 3, 4, 5},
   {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4,
    EventHandler[
     Style[2 -> 5, col], 
       {"MouseClicked" :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]
    }]]
```

The above code generates a graph that has two clickable objects (one edge, one vertex) however they both change color when one of the objects is clicked.  I suspected this is due to my `EventHandler` code and the events would trigger whenever the **Graph** is clicked.  The color change event is not thrown, however, if one of the other edges/vertices is clicked so I'm a bit stuck.

As an aside, I used `Rule` instead of `DirectedEdge` which seems to work although I don't know if this is the *right* way to make a graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use some functionalities `Graph`s are equiped with:

```
col[_] := Red;
b = Button[Style[#, col[#]], col[#] = col[#] /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red}] &;

Dynamic@Graph[
  {1, b@2, 3, b@4, 5},
  {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, b[2 -> 4], 2 -> 5}]
```

[image]

`Graph` allows us to put inside `Style` `Button` etc. This is the effect.

Perfect situation for You would be if `DynamicModule` is avalible, unfortunatelly it is not. Then You could create similar function to that above with scoped `col` and with different initialization value for each color.
I will try to work around that.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use different names for the color styles:

```
DynamicModule[{col}, 
 Dynamic@Graph[{EventHandler[
     Style[1, 
      col[1]], {"MouseClicked" :> (col[1] = 
         col[1] /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}], 2, 3, 4, 
    5}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 
    EventHandler[
     Style[2 -> 5, 
      col[2]], {"MouseClicked" :> (col[2] = 
         col[2] /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]}],
 Initialization :> {col[_] := Green}]
```