# Creating an Interactive Module that plots a graph and a highlighted vertex

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, modeling, interactive

For an assignment, I have to do the following:

Build an interactive model with two controls, `n` and `u`, that generates a random graph called `K` with `n` vertices and `2n` edges and highlights vertex `u` of graph `K`. When the user selects a different vertex `u` of `K`, you display graph `K` with vertex `u` shown with a different color and with a different size.

At the moment, my code is as follows:

```
K = RandomGraph[{n}, {2 n}];
Manipulate[HighlightGraph[K, {u}], {n, 1, 10, 1}, {u, 1, n, 1}]
```

I think I need to state that `u` is a vertex, but unsure how to fix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Alessia, try to not use single capital letters as variables because there are already some build ones. FYI: related topics: [Adding Dynamic functionality to a Graph](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27777/5478), [128347](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128347/5478), [116648](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116648/5478), [104718](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104718/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function using `SetDelayed` to evaluate `RandomGraph` every time you call the function. Here, `SeedRandom` is used, so that every time `RandomGraph` is called for a given `n`, it gives the same result.

```
graph[n_, u_, size_] := With[{},
  SeedRandom[1000];
  RandomGraph[{n, 2 n}, VertexSize -> {u -> size}]]
```

Then, in the `Manipulate` to change the color, `RandomColor[]` function can be used in the `Style` attribute.

```
Manipulate[
 HighlightGraph[
  graph[n, u, u/(5 n)], {Style[u, RandomColor[n][[u]]]}], {n, 5, 15, 
  1}, {u, 1, n, 1}, ControlType -> LabeledSlider]
```

[image]

Note: To get `2n` edges, value of `n` should be `>=` 5.